# priority queue and map

Tags: c++, stl, queue, lru

I do LRU cache in my programm. 
I have:

```
class DiadocCache : public IDiadocCache<K,T>
        {
        private:
             std::map<K, CacheEntry<T>> values_;
             std::priority_queue<?> timeQueue_;
        }
```

priority - it is the number of hits on a key in my case.

I put items in the std::map as follows:
values_.insert (std :: make_pair (key, CacheEntry  (value)));

How i can add elements in priority_queue?
And what types must be specified when creating a priority queue?
std::priority_queue<**?**>

Comment: Are you aware, that you cannot modify the elements inside the priority_queue?

Answer (score 0):

LRU can not be implemented with your current DS. you should be using DLL with hashing of each element. you can use list with unordered_hash or map.
as in current implementation you can not update the data of priority_queue.